# Create file from object dataURL

Tags: javascript, file, data-url

I have this object:

```
{dataURL: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwA…r/wALbpMM7gAAAANJREFUQ9S2TEBrmQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==...", 
type: "image/png"}
```

how can I create a file from this object?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "create a file"!

Comment: You may want to look at [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using javascript, you can't create file except IE on windows, but you can show this image by passing dataURL to src attribute if img tag. img tag can process on base64string and show image.

Comment: This is not entirely true, you can initiate downloads using _JavaScript_ (just you don't have control over where it ends up).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you can make an image with that base64 property as a source for it.

Example:

```
var obj = {
    dataURL: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwA…r/wALbpMM7gAAAANJREFUQ9S2TEBrmQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==...", 
    type: "image/png"
};

var image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = obj.dataURL;

document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Or, if you want also download that stuff immediately, then you should

```
var obj = {
    dataURL: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwA…r/wALbpMM7gAAAANJREFUQ9S2TEBrmQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==...", 
    type: "image/png"
};

window.location = obj.dataURL.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
```

Then the image will be downloaded as a file with name "download" or something like that.